# Binding a string doesn't show up, Binding another type does... WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I just started with WPF and databinding. First question on databinding. 
Databinding on {Binding Periode.Einde} where Einde is of type DateTime works,
{Binding Arrangement} where Arrangement is of type Enum works, {Binding Limo.Info} where Info is of type String doesn't work.
Somebody has an explanation for that?

```
<ListView Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Name="hups" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="BlueViolet" Opacity="80" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                        <Image Source="images\limousine-car-VIP-transport-128.png" Height="50"/>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Starttijdstip:" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Periode.Begin, ConverterCulture='nl-BE', StringFormat='dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Stoptijdstip:" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Periode.Einde, ConverterCulture='nl-BE', StringFormat='dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="BlueViolet" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock Text="Limo:" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Limo.Info}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Arrangement:" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Arrangement}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DockPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate with more information? What is the DataContext Class for the item template? Is Limo is property? Is Limo.Info is property?

Comment: Sure, string is empty or null.

Comment: You should be binding itemssource of your listview to an observablecollection<t>. T should have a public limo property which should have a public info property which has a value set. I guess one of those things isn't true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your binding expression `Text="{Binding Limo.Info}"` then if Limo.Info is of type string, then there are only 3 possible scenarios as to why nothing appears in your UI

1) `Limo` object is null

2) `Info` string is null or empty

3) `Limo.Info` is spelled incorrectly, and it's actually something else.

It has to be one of those 3 scenarios. check the objects you are passing into your `ListView`

Comment: 4) Either Limo or Info is not a public property.

Comment: yup @Clemens - forgot that one

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Limo is null. It's Entity Framework with Lazy Loading I think...

Comment: No need to write this as another answer. There is already the one that you accepted.